# Unable to enable-experimental-web-platform-features by command line for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-flags

I am not able to **enable-experimental-web-platform-features** flag by command line. I am using different user profile which is not the default one of chrome.

I am doing this by following:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --user-data-dir=D:/dev/chrome/profiles/sahi0 --enable-experimental-web-platform-features --incognito

Comment: Turns out it was working, but it was not replicated in chrome flags. So I was under impression that it's not working at all.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

From [a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765587/unable-to-enable-experimental-web-platform-features-by-command-line-for-chrome#comment82493999_47765587):

> Turns out it was working, but it was not replicated in chrome flags. So I was under impression that it's not working at all.

One cannot evaluate whether these items are working by looking only at `chrome://flags`; one needs to test actual functionality in practice.