# Bring up Chromium with flags

Tags: bash, chromium

I am trying to bring up chromium browser in Ubuntu with the flag --enable-experimental-web-platform-features enabled in my script, but after reboot the system, chromium still showed the flag was disabled.

chromium-browser --enable-experimental-web-platform-features

I know how to enable this flag manually after chromium is up, but the purpose of the script is to bring up chromium initially with --enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag up/enabled.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there already a chromium browser running before you do that invocation? If the command ends up joining to an existing browser process, then you don't have a new one started.

Comment: Also, see the preexisting question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765587/unable-to-enable-experimental-web-platform-features-by-command-line-for-chrome -- it's "unanswered", but only because the person who asked it added the resolution as a comment rather than an answer. (I just mirrored that to a community-wiki answer; should that answer receive any upvotes it'll become a valid close-as-duplicate target).

Comment: No, there was no an existed chromium before the script got called, because I reboot the system after every change or during the test, so the chromium browser was brought up freshly.

Comment: Did you follow the "preexisting question" link and evaluate whether the solution there applies?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the flag to the script works - I am able to test the new experimental features on the chromium. The fact that confused me at the beginning was that the flag remained disabled on the browser flags page.